# beginners guide to using the accelerometer?

Tags: android, accelerometer

I am planning out a game that I will be writing for android, and the accelerometer is something that I am not familiar with. Getting the tilt, and creating a vector for the player is a very important part of the game. I've read the documentation and various tutorials. Doing so was a little confusing b/c none of what I read relates to game programming. So I have a couple of questions:

How do I get a vector from a onSensorChange event?

How do I change this vector in a way that looks natural as the tilt lessens/advances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is many examples and tutorials will help u.

[Link 1](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/app-builder/a-quick-tutorial-on-coding-androids-accelerometer/472)

[Link 2](http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-development/accelerometer-example/)

[sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-andtutorials/tree/master/38-Sensors)

[Link 3](http://webhole.net/2011/08/20/android-sdk-accelerometer-example-tutorial/)

i sure some of this u see it before, but hope it help u.
and these two i'm sure will help u to understand what onSensorChange exactly do:-

[What happens when onSensorChanged() in called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12872844/what-happens-when-onsensorchanged-in-called-before-it-can-finish-the-current-e)

[Good Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11068571/getting-direction-vector-in-android)